# ArrayAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android

I'm beginner in Android Development!
I'm trying insert into Fragment parsing data
Trying to fix error but I have an error "
output cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка данных");
    mProgressDialog.show();
    new ParseSite().execute("http://www.babyblog.ru/magazine/");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.magazine, container, false);  
    ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , output));
    return view;
}
private class ParseSite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... arg) {
      List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
      try
      {
       HtmlHelper hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
        List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("razdel-name");

        for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = links.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {
          TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
          output.add(divElement.getText().toString());
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return output;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable 'output' has not been defined.

i.e.

```
 listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , output));
```

That variable is not in scope.

You attemot to use it in onCreate of your fragment, but it is declared in the ASyncTask class.

You need to go and read about ASyncTasks and how you work with them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads

as a shortcut, try this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

  ListView listview;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(
   // other stuff
   listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewData); 
   // remove the setAdapater line

}

private class ParseSite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

   // other stuff

   protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
      listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , output));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `output` variable is still null. You have to implement onPostExecute(List result) in your AsyncTask.
This will give you the output you want.

[this blogpos](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/using-asynctask.html)t can explain how `AsyncTask` works. But be careful, AsyncTask has a couple of hidden pitfalls. Read all about that [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html)

Comment: You can't access a variable defined in an inner class (`output`) from the outer class (`Fragment`), but he can do it the other way round if he moved output to the `Fragment`, then your answer would work.